# Iterating through a Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iteration, nsdictionary

I'm trying to iterate over an NSMutableDictionary and I cannot seem to get what I want. I have a dictionary mapping strings to colors like so...

```
squareColors = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                                                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                                                                nil]

                                                      forKeys: [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                                @"yellow",
                                                                @"blue",
                                                                @"green",
                                                                @"purple",
                                                                @"orange",
                                                                nil]];
```

Over time the value of each entry will increase. Every once in a while I want to look into the dictionary and select the color with the highest count. How might I do that? Here's what I'm trying, but I'm unfamiliar with blocks.

```
__block int mostSquares = 0;
__block NSString* color = @"";
/* Look through the dictionary to find the color with the most number of squares */
[squareColors enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
   NSLog(@"%@ => %@", key, obj);
   NSInteger count = [key integerValue];
   if (count > mostSquares)
   {
        color = key;
        mostSquares = count;
   }
}];
```

Comment: So what does not work? Code seems fine to me.

Comment: @Perception because the initializer method he used requires it.

Comment: When running through the debugger, the block itself is entirely skipped for some reason, and the color/mostSquares values are never reassigned. I always get color = "" and mostSquares = 0.

Comment: This actually sounds like a perfect job for a NSCountedSet.

Comment: Modern ObjC syntax: NSMutableDictionary * squareColors = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@[
                                          @"yellow" : @(0),
                                          @"blue" : @(0),
                                          @"green" : @(0),
                                          @"purple" : @(0),
                                          @"orange" : @(0)]
                                          ];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a very simple bug in your code. This line:

```
NSInteger count = [key integerValue];
```

should be:

```
NSInteger count = [obj integerValue];
```

'key' is the color name, `obj` is the number. As you have it, `count` gets set to `0` for each iteration because calling `integerValue` on a non-numeric string gives you `0`.

Comment: Ah! Good catch. Thanks very much. Now I can use the block iteration instead of a for `(id key in dict)`, which turns out to be 40% faster.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using your example:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayNumbers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:0],
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:2],
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:6],
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt:4],
                                nil];
NSMutableArray *arrayColours =  [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 @"yellow",
                                 @"blue",
                                 @"green",
                                 @"purple",
                                 @"orange",
                                 nil];
NSMutableDictionary *squareColors = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:arrayNumbers
                                                                       forKeys:arrayColours];
NSUInteger indexOfArray = [arrayNumbers indexOfObject:[arrayNumbers valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"]];
NSLog (@"Colour with largest value is %@", [arrayColours objectAtIndex:indexOfArray]);
```

Comment: That's not using a dictionary to solve the problem. The only reason I'm using arrays is to initialize a dictionary. From that point on I don't update or touch the arrays.

Comment: What the? Your dictionary IS made of arrays. And if you don't touch or update them, why are you using mutable arrays anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Can you store your Keys into an array and iterate using that array? That would probably be the most efficient solution, since you'll need to know every key anyway.